# Propagating Baggage using B3 / Zipkin and Spring Cloud Sleuth

Tags: spring-cloud-sleuth

I understand that with the advent of Spring Cloud Sleuth 3.x.x, you need to specify the name of baggage headers to be propagated to remote components like this:

```yaml
# in application.yaml

spring:
  sleuth:
    baggage:
      remote-fields: <name of the header>
```

For custom headers I think this is fine. I was wondering what this looks like for B3 / Zipkin if baggage should be transferred.

I remember a [discussion about B3 not specifying baggage](https://github.com/openzipkin/b3-propagation/issues/22) but that there was also a kind of "convention" that fields prefixed with `baggage-` were forwarded.

**Question 1:** Is this correct, and is it still the case, or was that removed in Sleuth 3.x.x?

**Question 2:** If it was removed, does that mean that for B3 / Zipkin the baggage headers an application forwards will always have to be *explicitly* specified using the `remote-fields` property?

**Question 3:** How are standardized baggage headers treated by Sleuth, e.g. [W3C Trace Context Baggage](https://www.w3.org/TR/baggage/). Are they forwarded automatically, or do they need to be explicitly specified using `remote-fields`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Question 1: Is this correct, and is it still the case, or was that removed in Sleuth 3.x.x?

We don't prefix the baggage with `baggage-` or `baggage_` anymore. Whatever you set as baggage (e.g. `foo`) will be set as is in the headers.

> Question 2: If it was removed, does that mean that for B3 / Zipkin the baggage headers an application forwards will always have to be explicitly specified using the remote-fields property?

Yes.

> Question 3: How are standardized baggage headers treated by Sleuth, e.g. W3C Trace Context Baggage. Are they forwarded automatically, or do they need to be explicitly specified using remote-fields?

They are forwarded automatically. Check this part of the docs for more information https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-sleuth/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#how-to-change-context-propagation